# Dynamic font size scaling

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to scale the font size of a text view in swiftui depending on the frame size of the text view?
What I try to solve:
I have a text string which I want to display. On an iPhone 12 Pro Max my text string fits into one line. If my apps runs on an iPhone SE the font size has do reduce to fit in this line.

sound this confusing? ;-)

How should I try to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .minimumScaleFactor modifier, which reduces the font size as required to fit within the frame. It's often used with a .lineLimit modifier as well.

```
        Text("Hello")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems the modifier I've been looking for!